# How come bootstrap is overwriting my css body?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Ever since I updated to Bootstrap 4 it's updated my body and overwritten it so that the background is always white.

I have tried setting a class to be more specific, still doesn't work. Can someone help?

[image: Inspect Element]:

Comment: Did you try including your CSS after bootstrap's?

Comment: Please try to reorder the link tags for `bootstrap` and `your own css`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please reorder the `link tags` for bootstrap and `your own css`

e.g

```
<link ..... href="css/bootstrap.min.css"....></link>
<link ..... href="css/styleIndex.css"....></link>
```

then `your style` will overwrite the `default bootstrap style`

Comment: Thanks Jin! Owe you one.

Answer (score 2):

Since your CSS file is no more specific than the Bootstrap styles, it all depends on the order that the styles appear in your HTML.

So, you could either re-order the style files, or (and I think this option is better) use a class on your body to set the background color.

When using the class, make sure your style looks like this:

```
body.class-name{

}
```

That will be more specific than `body`.

Bootstrap has many (customizable) color classes built in. If you're compiling the SCSS files yourself, you can also use the included color variables to make your own styles.

In fact, if you just set the `$body-color` variable before compiling your bootstrap CSS file, you won't have to write any styles.

For more customization options. check [the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/).